# Black Box Renders Instead of 3D Object

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-4

This base code was working well for 2D objects, but will not render the 3D object that I have the vertices and index for.  At first I thought it was the shader, but the shader works well for everything else.  I wrote a few cout tests to make sure that the draw call was being reached, and the system does indeed call the draw function.  However, I just get a black screen.

Is this a screen size problem? From my understanding, OpenGL goes from 0 to 1 on its coordinate system, but if you use large numbers it scales them for you.  I was reading about glViewport, is this a function I need to use?

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>


void UProcessInput(GLFWwindow* window);

//vertex shader
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 440 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"  //vertices entries
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = position;\n"  //position for shader given all our matrices and transformations
"}\n\0";

//fragment shader
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 440 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragmentColor;\n"
"uniform vec4 uColor;"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   fragmentColor = uColor;\n"
"}\n\0";

static unsigned int CompileShader(const std::string& source, unsigned int type)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}


static unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader) {

    unsigned int programID = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(fragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glAttachShader(programID, vs);
    glAttachShader(programID, fs);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glValidateProgram(programID);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    std::cout << "Shader program successfully created and returned" << std::endl;
    return programID;

}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;


    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Helloooooooooooo", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glewInit();
    
    float vertices[] =
    {
       2.5f, 7.5f, 0.0f,      // 0
       -2.5f, 7.5f, 0.0f,     // 1
       2.5f, 12.5f, 0.0f,     // 2
       -2.5f, 12.5f, 0.0f,    // 3
       1.0f, 9.0f, 6.0f,      // 4
       -1.0f, 9.0f, 6.0f,     // 5
       1.0f, 11.0f, 6.0f,     // 6
       -1.0f, 11.0f, 6.0f,    // 7
       0.0f, 10.0f, 7.0f,     // 8

    };

    unsigned int indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 1, 5,
        0, 4, 5,
        0, 4, 6,
        0, 2, 6,
        1, 5, 7,
        1, 3, 7,
        2, 3, 7,
        2, 6, 7,
        4, 6, 5,
        5, 6, 7,
        4, 8, 6,
        4, 8, 5,
        5, 8, 7,
        7, 8, 6,
    };

    unsigned int VBO;

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);

    unsigned int IBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int shader = CreateShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "uColor");
    glUniform4f(location, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);

    
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        UProcessInput(window);  //waits for user input

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  //checks to make sure a fragment is supposed to be rendered (front) or not (behind other rendered fragments)

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  //depth buffer stores depth value generated after depth testing
        /* Render here */

        glUniform4f(location, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        std::cout << "Triangles Drawn" << std::endl;

       /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void UProcessInput(GLFWwindow* window) //if user hits ESC, close window
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}
```

Comment: Without any view transformation, I suspect the whole geometry is outside of the clip box. Try coordinates with each component in the range [-1, 1]. FYI: [OpenGL Transformation](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)

Comment: How do I go about getting these coordinates in clip space besides changing all the coordinates?  Is there not some sort of scaling feature that will normalize coordinates?

Comment: One option is to provide other coordinates. The other option is to process (i.e. transform) coordinates from world space to screen space by applying the combination of multiple matrices. Two notable are the view matrix (the inverse of the camera matrix which describes the pos/dir of camera in world space) and the projection matrix which describes the projection of camera space into screen space. Somewhere in between the coordinates "pass" the clip space. For details, please, refer to the above link which is surely more accurate than my memory.

Comment: Transformations are an important part of OpenGL rendering. Yet another link: [Learn OpenGL - Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations)